# getting nullpointer exception when using getReceiverInfo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Iam not able to get the value specified in metadata in the reciever file, iam getting a null pointer exception.

In the manifest file i have specified

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">

                <action
                    android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
                    android:enabled="true" />
                <meta-data android:name="Algorithm" android:value="AES"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and in the reciever iam specifying

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         ActivityInfo appi = null;
        try {
            appi = context.getPackageManager().getReceiverInfo(new ComponentName(context,"intgafaes.mobileafaes.androidafaes.securesms.ADDFriendSmsReceiver"), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }   

        Bundle bundle1 = appi.metaData;

        String value = bundle1.getString("Algorithm");
        System.out.println("Value is "+value);

        if(value.equals("AES"))
        {
            System.out.println("entered into onRecieve");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always have null check when you are retreiving values..

```
if(appi != null){
Bundle bundle1 = appi.metaData;
}
```

i don't think it is able to get **"intgafaes.mobileafaes.androidafaes.securesms.ADDFriendSmsReceiver"**.

..
 and your try catch is of no use in this code..

it does nothing... atleast it should have return statement so that an Exception does't occur..

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         ActivityInfo appi = null;
        try {
            appi = context.getPackageManager().getReceiverInfo(new ComponentName(context,"intgafaes.mobileafaes.androidafaes.securesms.ADDFriendSmsReceiver"), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }   

        Bundle bundle1 = appi.metaData;

        String value = bundle1.getString("Algorithm");
        System.out.println("Value is "+value);

        if(value.equals("AES"))
        {
            System.out.println("entered into onRecieve");
        }
```

Comment: Iam getting the package name correctly but not able to retrieve the value of Algorithm specified in meta-data tag

Answer (score 0):

in the reciever i have to declare the meta-data tag after intent-filter tag then i can access the data using the same above code

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">

                <action
                    android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
                    android:enabled="true" />

            </intent-filter>
             <meta-data android:name="Algorithm" android:value="AES"/>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi @user1203673 can you plz tell me how i can declare the above mentioned code dynamically ??? We can create/register a receiver dynamically, we can specify filter and action also. So my question is how we can add the meta tag ??

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the meta-data for this element in AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
```

If you want to get the ActivityInfo of this element you should call:

```
appi = context.getPackageManager().getReceiverInfo(
        new ComponentName(context, "<yourrootpackage>.SmsReceiver"),
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

If you call this inside the `SmsReceiver` (as you do in the code you provided), you might want to avoid the hard coded string and instead do:

```
appi = context.getPackageManager().getReceiverInfo(
        new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()),
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Or is that just a copy paste confusion that you are querying the info using a completely different class name?